# Understanding a Set Theory Equation on Decoding a Linear value Into a Logarithmic value

Tags: logarithms

I'm currently writing a series of equations into python code (I should note, for fun!) and am having trouble understanding this. From my ignorant perspective it looks like a set with a series of variables. The following equation encodes a 16-bit integer value Vp (unsigned, only positive values up to 65,536 ) as an 12-bit (4096) integer value Vi, theoretically taking a value from a linear to logarithmic space.

[image: Equation]

If anyone could explain would be incredibly grateful!

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that N >> q means a right shift by q places of the binary expression of N ?

Comment: You can basically think of this notation as an "if statement" or like a ternary operator (or a case statement...). After the left curly brace there are two columns. The second column tells you under what condition to "choose" a row, and the first column tells you what value to use when you have chosen that row. Have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272030/how-to-do-if-and-else-in-math

Comment: @Jean, To me it seems like it might be! Since they asked about something that "looks like a set with a series of variables". I guess we'll see! OP, are you asking about what the notation with the curly brace with two rows inside it means?

Comment: @ Izaak van Dongen Looking at it again, you might be right ...

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes! So the top row and bottom row are an IF statement? If I'm to understand correctly so as a RHS expression it is IF Vp < 1024, Vi=Vp. If Vp >= 1024 follow Jean's equation bellow.

Comment: That's it .....

Comment: @DevereuxGabriel, Yes, exactly. Of course Python has a built-in right bitshift operator, also denoted by `>>`, so in Python, you could literally write `vi = vp if vp < 1024 else 512 * q + (vp >> q)`, or an if statement containing the assignments `vi = vp` and `vi = 512 * q + (vp >> q)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attempted to unveil a part of the mysterious definition. Here is what I have "deciphered".

Let us start from the definition of $q$:

$$q=\log_2(v_p)-9+\varepsilon \ \ \ \ \text{where}\ \ 0\le \varepsilon < 1$$

As a consequence:

$$2^q=2^{\log_2(v_p)}2^{-9}2^{\varepsilon}$$

which is equivalent to :

$$2^q=\frac{v_p}{512} K  \ \ \ \ \text{where}\ \ 1\le K < 2\tag{1}$$

The curly brackets clearly mean the two different expressions $v_i$ can take according to the position of $v_p$ with respect to $1024$.

Let us consider the interesting case $v_p \ge 1024$, where  we can convert the RHS expression into:

$$v_i=512 q + \frac{v_p}{2^q}\tag{2}$$

(explanations below)

Plugging (1) into (2):

$$v_i=512 q + \frac{512}{K}$$

$$v_i=512(q+K')  \ \ \ \ \text{where}\ \ 0.5 < K':=\frac{1}{K} \le 1\tag{3}$$

$$v_i=512(\log_2(v_p)-9+\varepsilon+K')  \ \ \ \ \text{where}\ \ \begin{cases}0.5 < K' \le 1 \\ 0\le \varepsilon < 1 \end{cases}\tag{4}$$

where, indeed, $v_i$ is "asymptotically proportional" to $\log(v_p)$.

Explanation for expression (2): Notation N >> q means "right shift by $q$ places of the binary expression of $N$", amounting to a division by $2^q$.

Comment: thank you! A few Q's - the introduction of  & K is to take into account the right shit of Vp>>Q? I'm mostly stumped by the bottom statement Q is the integer part of the difference

Comment: Saying that "$q$ is the integer part of $B$" is the same as saying that "$q=B+\varepsilon$ for a certain positive $\varepsilon < 1$". It is exactly what I say in the very first equation with $B=\log_2(v_p)-9$.

Comment: No: the rightshift $v_p>>q$ is taken into account when I write it $\frac{v_p}{2^q}$. For example $(v_p>>1) =\frac{v_p}{2}$ (rightshifting by 1 is like dividing by 2)

Comment: Copy copy, that makes a lot of sense! My last question is, how does one determine the positive value of  and/or K.

Comment: (I have rectified the last formulations in my answer)/ Answer to your last question : One cannot truly determine them. It just gives a bracketing of the answer; as the sum $K'+\varepsilon$ is between $0$ and $1.5$, one gets: $512(\log_2(v_p)-9) <v_i<512(\log_2(v_p)-7.5)$.

Comment: Maybe connected to your issue: https://janmr.com/blog/2010/09/computing-the-integer-binary-logarithm/