# Representation of function applied to pairs generated from Cartesian product

Tags: notation

I'm attempting to define an algorithm using math notation which runs a function on value pairs, the pairs are generated as a result of a Cartesian product of all elements in set and if the result of the function for one of
the pairs exceeds 2 then return the value of the function.

Is this correct ?  :

$$
s = \{s1, s2, s3, s4\dots\}
$$

$$
\varphi_1 : function(s_a , s_b)
$$

$$
\forall (s\times s) \varphi_1 > 2 \rightarrow value(\varphi_1)
$$

I accessed if notation from [Representing IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... in math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15629/representing-if-then-else-in-math-notation/15633#15633)

Update :

Each member of the set represents a group of characters and the function returns 2 if  $s_a$ contains more characters than $s_b$.

So in this example where

$$
s = \{"test words" , "test"\}
$$

Cartesian product of s is ("testwords" , "test"),("test" , "testwords"),("test" , "test"),("words" , "words")

```
function applied to ("testwords" , "test") returns 2
function applied to ("test" , "testwords") returns nothing
function applied to ("test" , "test") returns nothing
function applied to ("testwords" , "testwords") returns nothing
```

Comment: Mathematically what you have written looks strange to me, but I don't really understand the input or output of your function (maybe a small example would help?). It's more common to see a piecewise function for "if, then" type formulas; $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\text{1st option}, & \text{(implicit ``if'') 1st condition} \\ \text{2nd option}, & \text{2nd condition}  \\ \text{etc.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @pjs36 please see question update