# How to express logical conditions when writing constraints algebraicly?

Tags: optimization, notation, linear-programming

I am currently writing my thesis and am developing an MILP optimization model. 
I have a lot of constraints that should only be created if certain conditions regarding the respective parameters of the underlying sets are true.

I have attached an example of a constraint to illustrate, how I currently wrote them: [example of a contraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbhqL.png).

I did this based on this post: 
[Representing IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... in math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15629/representing-if-then-else-in-math-notation).
This equation basically states that the end of a process equals the starting time plus its duration. But this equation must only be created for a certain subset of processes J, otherwise the model is infeasible. The two conditions regarding **m** and **lvl** are connected by a logical **AND**.

- et:    end time, variable
- st:    start time, variable
- d:     duration, parameter
- m,lvl: properties of the individual processes in set J, parameters

Even though this notation feels natural (to me at least), I cannot find this notation in the literature on the topic.

Is it possible to write constraints like this? Are their major issues with this type of notation?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I often use implications for this, using $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for the comment. Here are two [examples](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NNwydNBD8NSZAsp24zASnKmxboqvnNTg). Is this how you meant it? I think the second (eq. 41) would be more appropriate in my case, because if and only if the conditions hold the constraint must be created.