# How can I represent/specify this Haskell function in mathematical and logical notation?

Tags: logic, notation, programming

Below is a Haskell function definition that computes the $nth$ Fibonancci number.

```
fib :: Int  -> Int  
fib 0  = 0  -- equation 1   
fib n  = if n == 1 then 1 else      
   (fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2))  -- equation 2
```

The definition is a mixture of pattern matching (equation 1) and an `if_then_else` function (equation 2). This is a rather unnatural way to write this function. But I am wondering is there a notational way to combine pattern matching and  `if_then_else` ? See [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15629/representing-if-then-else-in-math-notation).

Here is my attempt to represent/specify the Haskell code as a mathematical function:
\begin{align*}
\forall n \colon  \mathbb{Z}~~~fib(n) \triangleq \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
0, & n = 0\\
fib (n)\triangleq\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
1, & n = 1\\
fib(n - 1)+fib(n - 2), & otherwise\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

Here is my attempt to represent/specify the Haskell code in first order logic, with equality:
\begin{align*}
(\forall n \colon  \mathbb{Z}  \colon ((n=0) \implies  (fib(n) = 0)))  \land \\
(\forall n \colon  \mathbb{Z}  \colon ((n=1) \implies  (fib(n) = 1))) \land \\
(\forall n \colon  \mathbb{Z}  \colon (\neg((n=1) \lor (n=0)) \implies  (fib(n)  = fib(n - 1)+fib(n - 2))))
\end{align*}

**Questions**: Are these attempts reasonable? Can they be improved?

Comment: Why do you handle the $n=1$ case with an `if` statement instead of pattern matching?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, of course that would be the more uniform way. But I want to understand  how to represent the definition using a mixed approach.

Comment: In programming different implementation might have very different behavior when it comes to running time and memory use. But in mathematics such things don't matter; it's only the final value that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could write it as
$$
\mathsf{fib}(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n=0$}, \\
1 & \text{if $n=1$}, \\
\mathsf{fib}(n-2)+\mathsf{fib}(n-1) & \text{otherwise}. \\
\end{cases}
$$

A mathematician would normally write something like $F_0=0,\ F_1=1,\ F_n=F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}$ for $n=2,3,4,\ldots$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think mixing pattern matching and if_then_else was probably a bad idea.